# How to remove redundant [] in python

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
a=[[[[5]]]]
```

and I would like to reduce the nests and get result as below:

```
a=[5]
```

I think it's not a big deal, but I don't know how to do it and find no way to this....
Thank you very much

Comment: Write this `a=a[0][0][0]`

Comment: If you have a single element list, you can simplify the recursion step... but that's for you to figure out.

Comment: Maybe you could avoid creating the nested list in the first place?

Comment: @Chris_Rands actually this is not I created but read from other data. 
and the real data is not so simple but like this:
[[ [[1,2,3,4,5,],[2,3,4,5,6] ] ,[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]  ]]
there are too many useless [[ ]]

Comment: @laure I think this a good idea, but something bad is actually I don't know how many nest in my variable read from the data